# How to get the roots of a quartic function when given a quadratic factor

Tags: polynomials, roots

> We have the function $$x^4 + 4x^3 - 17x^2 -24x + 36 = 0.$$ $x^2 -x - 6$ is a factor of this function. Find all the roots of the polynomial.

So we have $(x-3)(x+2)$, and since it is a quartic we need 2 more solutions. Intuitively I'd say you should divide our quartic by our factors to get another quadratic, but I'm sure there exists a quicker/simpler method. My question is what is the quickest method to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is spot on. [Polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) is the quickest, at least the standard, route to go here, barring any immediate "sighting" of another root. Divide your quartic by the quadratic $x^2 - x - 6$ to obtain a quadratic quotient, then factor the quotient (or use the quadratic formula) to find any remaining roots, if they exist.

Your quartic divided by the quadratic $x^2 - x - 6$ gives the quadratic quotient $$x^2 + 5x -6 = (x+6)(x - 1)$$

$$x^4 + 4x^3 -17x^2 -24x + 36 = (x-3)(x + 2)(x + 6)(x - 1)$$

So there exist four roots.

---

You can a find brief tutorial on polynomial long division at the [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/multiplying-factoring-expression/dividing_polynomials/v/algebraic-long-division), to better familiarize yourself with it.

Comment: How would one do that? Seeing as not all terms in the quartic have an $x$?

Comment: Are you familiar with polynomial division?

Comment: I don't really think so. My algebraic skills are not up to par, at high school I never even encountered a cubic..

Comment: Phaptitude - See the link I added in my answer. See also the [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/multiplying-factoring-expression/dividing_polynomials/v/algebraic-long-division) for a video tutorial on dividing polynomials. It's a process that's just like long division.

Comment: Oh wow, how can I never have been introduced to polynomial long division?! Is wikipedia's notation standard/correct notation?

Comment: @amWhy: Nice answer, link, discussion +1

Comment: @Phaptitude Yes, indeed, it's pretty standard notation. See also the [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/multiplying-factoring-expression/dividing_polynomials/v/algebraic-long-division) for brief tutorials on polynomial long division.

Comment: @amWhy It's straightforward, thanks. It's really helpful, also for non-polynomials.